# Detecting operator +

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I am trying to detect the operator plus on a class with the following code which is not working with sfinae any experts have any ideas on what I am missing.

Also the complier dies when you remove the operator + on the type you are trying to detect it on

```
    template<class T1, class T2>
        class has_addition_operator
        {
        private:

            typedef char no;

            static auto has(T1* a, T2* b) -> decltype( *a + *b);

            static char has(...);

        public:
            enum{
                value = (sizeof( has(new T1(), new T2())) != sizeof(no))
            };

        };


struct point{
        int x, y;

        point operator + (point const & o){

            point r = *this;
            r.x += o.x;
            r.y += o.y;
            return r;

        }

    };

    bool has = liboperator::has_addition_operator<point,point>::value;
```

The compiler has the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: liboperator, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  liboperator.cpp
1>c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\has_addition_operator.h(15): error C2784: 'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr> std::operator +(_String_iterator<_Mystr>::difference_type,std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>' from 'point'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(420) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
1>          c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator.cpp(26) : see reference to class template instantiation 'liboperator::has_addition_operator<T1,T2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T1=point,
1>              T2=point
1>          ]
1>c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\has_addition_operator.h(15): error C2784: 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Mystr> std::operator +(_String_const_iterator<_Mystr>::difference_type,std::_String_const_iterator<_Mystr>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Mystr>' from 'point'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(288) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
1>c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\has_addition_operator.h(15): error C2784: 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> std::operator +(_Diff,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'point'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1947) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
1>c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\has_addition_operator.h(15): error C2784: 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,_Size> std::operator +(_Array_iterator<_Ty,_Size>::difference_type,std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,_Size>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,_Size>' from 'point'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1801) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
1>c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\has_addition_operator.h(15): error C2784: 'std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size> std::operator +(_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size>::difference_type,std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size>' from 'point'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1662) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
1>c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\has_addition_operator.h(15): error C2784: 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> std::operator +(_Diff,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'point'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1226) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
1>c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\has_addition_operator.h(15): error C2784: 'std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> std::operator +(_Diff,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'point'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1031) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
1>c:\projects\liboperator\liboperator\liboperator\has_addition_operator.h(15): error C2676: binary '+' : 'point' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Be more specific - what errors are you getting, what compiler are you using and what does 'the complier dies' mean?

Comment: Ok will paste the output

Comment: Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Won't this approach fail if T1+T2 produces a type of same size as `char`?

Comment: Probably. But I want to get it working before I add in a full specialisation for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SFINAE stands for **"Substitution failure** is not an error". Note the bolded part - there's nothing to substitute in your checker function

```
static auto has(T1* a, T2* b) -> decltype( *a + *b);
```

because it's not a template itself. When you instantiate the trait class, its signature is already known and whatever type it was instantiated with it's supposed to have `operator+`.

You need to make `has` a template itself. Something like this should work (untested):

```
template<typename U1, typename U2>
static constexpr auto has(int*)
    -> decltype( std::declval<U1>() + std::declval<U2>(), yes() )
```

Where `yes` is a typedef for a type with different size than `sizeof(no)`. The way the above is written, there's no chance for compiler to deduce `U1` and `U2` so you need to specify them explicitly. Therefore, you'll need to make the fallback function a template, too.

Comment: Totally correct I was missing the function being a template so SFINAE never applied. Thank you.

Comment: @BlairDavidson me too, actually, haha. Editing.

Comment: Hi you also helped me get my first commit for my project liboperator on https://github.com/loosechainsaw/liboperator

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the "has operator" case:

```
static auto has(T1* a, T2* b) -> decltype( *a + *b);
```

You are telling the compiler that there is *always* an overload of `has` that accepts a `T1*` and a `T2*` and returns... the type of the expression `T1 + T2`. But this expression has a type only if an addition operator is available.

This gets you into a loop: in order to determine if an `operator+` exists (to populate `value`) the compiler has to determine the return type of `operator+`... which might not exist!

Comment: Thanks mate. Will have a play

Comment: @BlairDavidson: To be frank I 'm not sure if this is at all possible.